# bits shift exceeding width of type in C

Tags: c, operating-system, bit, bit-shift, integer-overflow

I have a uint64_t variable called vpn and I'm trying to get its left 9 bits.
I know vpn is 45 bits long, so I tried the following:

```
uint64_t nineMSB = (vpn & (511 << 36)) >> 36;
```

but I get the following warning:

```
left shift count >= width of type
```

Why is that? 511 is 9 ones in binary so 511 << 36 should give me 45 bits, and I'm doing an AND with a uint64_t so the result should not exceed 64 bits..

Thank you!

Comment: 511 is of type `int`. Try `511ULL`

Comment: `511` is `int`. Try `511ull`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constant `511` has type `int`.  Your system most likely has a 32-bit `int`, so this means you're shifting a value by an amount larger than its bit length.  Doing so triggers [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

This is dictated by section 6.5.7p3 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) regarding bitwise shift operators:

> The integer promotions are performed on each of the operands. The type
> of the result is that  of  the  promoted  left  operand. **If  the
> value  of  the  right  operand  is  negative  or is greater than or
> equal to the width of the promoted left operand, the behavior is
> undefined.**

You can fix this by using the `ULL` suffix on the constant, which will give it type `unsigned long long` which is guaranteed to be at least 64 bits in length.

```
uint64_t nineMSB = (vpn & (511ULL << 36)) >> 36;
```

Answer (score 1):

integer constants without any suffixes or prefixes have type of `int`. On many systems `int` is 32bit long, but it can also be only 16bits long (avr port).

```
uint64_t foo(uint64_t vpn)
{
    uint64_t nineMSB = (vpn & (511ULL << 36)) >> 36;
    return nineMSB;
}

uint64_t foo1(uint64_t vpn)
{
    uint64_t nineMSB = (vpn & ((uint64_t)511 << 36)) >> 36;
    return nineMSB;
}
```

Comment: Re “integer constants without any suffixes have type of `int`”: The type depends on the value and form (e.g., hexadecimal), not just the suffix or lack thereof.